# get session data by cookies CraftSessionId

Tags: plugin-development, craft-pro

Is there a service method I can use to get (any kind of) session data by giving the cookies CraftSessionId as a parameter?

if would look something like this. 
`craft()->userSession->getSessionBySessionId($craftSessionId)`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you thinking there would be multiple PHP sessions for a user?  Or are you just looking to see how to read from and write to session?

Comment: Im using the ElementAPI (https://github.com/pixelandtonic/) . I see that you wrote it. Great :-).

Comment: So with this plugin I want to make a json API for Android and IOS apps. I want to create API urls to log the user in and authenticate the user.

Comment: I wanted to use craft()->userSession methods for this in the API but since this uses php SESSION I thought that it will only work when you visit the page with a browser, not when making calls from Android and IOS apps. eg. craft()->userSession->isLoggedIn I dont think will work in this case (am I correct?).
So I want to make a API url that can log the user in, and give some kind of a session id in the response. Then the device can make other api calls and include this session id so that I can authenticate each call the user makes. Is this the way to go about it? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @SiteHopper I'm attempting to do exactly the same thing - I'm using the ElementAPI for a client side app and would like to authenticate api calls. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd use PHP's session for this at all, but recently posted some thoughts on a similar question here https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14188/57 about using custom tokens or authorization headers to perform the authorization.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I am now working on expanding the plugin with a function that creates a custom token.

Comment: If you can share it, would love to see what you come up with when you're done!